# Eclipse code template based on highlight

Tags: java, eclipse

In the Eclipse platform, I want to create java custom code template based on a highlighted field name. for example, I highlight a field name, "name", right click and then insert a code template base on the "name". what is the variable name for the highlighted field ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Code Templates as configured in the Preferences in 'Java > Code Style > Code Templates' don't support this.

For editor templates as configured in 'Java > Editor > Templates' `${word_selection}` is possibly what you want.